# Exporting the report itself, not the data from access 2010

Tags: ms-access

as the title says, I would like to export the report itself.

I have two version of an access database, everything in these two is the same except they made a copy to use in 2014 and one to use in 2015... and there is this one report that is not present in the 2015 access file.
So is it possible to take it out of the 2014 file ? The right-click export function seems to only be for the data generated for the report.

Comment: you need to use the "import from access" wizard from the "External data" tab to import objects from another Access database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open both databases and the navigation panes.

Right-click and copy the report in the source database.

Right-click the navigation pane in the target database and paste the report.